# display datas from one-to-many relation .net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

first of all im real beginner with c# and .net i started 10 days ago so
im trying to display datas from a one-to-many relation but i have an error *System.NullReferenceException : 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*(i checked db there are datas in this table) and i dont understand why. I read many post about this but it never works, my code is almost the same than the example on the microsoft doc page but mine doesnt work.

**model**

```
        [Display(Name = "Formations")]
        public virtual ICollection<Courses> Course { get; set; }

    }

    public class Courses
    {
        [Key]
        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Formations")]
        public string Course { get; set; }

        public virtual Users users { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
       public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
       {
           if (id == null)
           {
               return NotFound();
           }

           var users = await _context.Users
               .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
           if (users == null)
           {
               return NotFound();
           }

           return View(users);
```

**View**

```
            @foreach (var item in Model.Course)
                { 
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Course)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
```

Comment: first you need to find where the nullreference exception is comming from. And then you can check how to prevent this. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4660186/7968203

Comment: the error is coming from my loop in the view if its what you mean.

Comment: This is possibly because the courses property is not loaded. Include the courses while searching user. `var users = await _context.Users.Include(x => x.Course)
               .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);`

Answer (score 0):

I asume that your model is of type `User`.
When querying for an entity (`User`), related entities (`Courses`) are not read automatically from the database, therefore your collection is/was `null`.

You can change that by using `Include()` in your Linq query: `await _context.Users.Include(u => u.Courses).FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);`

Just some small additional suggestions to improve your code, which helps you understand what's going on:

- Rename your `Courses` class to `Course` since your class only represent one single course.
- Rename the `Course` property to `Courses` since it is a collection of many objects of type `Course`
- Initialize your course collection with an empty list/hash set like so `public virtual public virtual ICollection<Courses> Course { get; set; } = new HashSet<Course>();` to avoid a null reference exception
- In your view, rename `item` to `course`. "Foreach (single) course in (many) courses" is much better to read and unserstand

Comment: I tried to initialize my collection with an empty list when i was looking for how to fix my problem, i had not error anymore but my loop didnt display anything so i thought it was not the right thing to do. Anyway i did it with your code and everything works fine thank you very much for your help. This little project is for a job so if i get it i'll owe you one ;)

Comment: The initialization of the collection is just to avoid a null reference exception like in your original case when a relation has not been loaded properly. An empty list resulting in showing no items is better than a program that crashes when it tries to access properties of a non exiting object. I wish you good luck with your job application! Hoping for beer as a reward :D

Answer (score 0):

fix the action

```
 var users = await _context.Users.Include(i=>i.Course)
               .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
```

since your are usind displayfor you will have to replace foreach loop by for loop

```
@model User
....
@if (Model.Course!=null)
{
  @for (var i=0; i<= Model.Course.Count; i+=1)
                { 
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model=> model.Course[i].Course)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
}
```